# Akka https ssl localhost testing

Tags: akka-http

I am trying to setup akka https locally, in a way that certificate does not need to be installed on every server ( I want that it can be run on jenkins build, or other machines ).

This way I am creating certs:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key
openssl req -sha256 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj '/CN=localhost'
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
cat server.crt server.key > cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -out mykeystore.pkcs12  -name akka-http-test -noiter -nomaciter
```

( tried also using mkcert tool )

Now scala code:

```
def createHttpsContext(): HttpsConnectionContext = {
    val password: Array[Char] = "changeit".toCharArray
    val ks: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
    val keystore: InputStream = {
      getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("mykeystore.pkcs12")
    }

    require(keystore != null, "Keystore required!")
    ks.load(keystore, password)

    val keyManagerFactory: KeyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    keyManagerFactory.init(ks, password)

    val tmf: TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    tmf.init(ks)

    val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers, tmf.getTrustManagers, new SecureRandom)
    val https: HttpsConnectionContext = akka.http.scaladsl.ConnectionContext.httpsServer(sslContext)
    https
  }

def createHttpsApiServer()(implicit system: ActorSystem) = {
    val routes: Route = get { complete("Hello world!") }
    val httpsContext = createHttpsContext()
    Http().newServerAt("127.0.0.1", 2001).enableHttps(httpsContext).bind(routes)
}
```

and test code:

```
private def runStopServerHttpsRequest()(implicit system: ActorSystem): Unit = {
    val trustfulSslContext: HttpsConnectionContext = {
      object NoCheckX509TrustManager extends X509TrustManager {
        override def checkClientTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = ()
        override def checkServerTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = ()
        override def getAcceptedIssuers: Array[X509Certificate] = Array[X509Certificate]()
      }
      val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
      context.init(Array[KeyManager](), Array(NoCheckX509TrustManager), null)
      context
      ConnectionContext.httpsClient(context)
    }

    val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, "https://127.0.0.1:2001/")
    val connectionFlow = Http().outgoingConnectionHttps("127.0.0.1", 2001, connectionContext = trustfulSslContext)

    Source.single(request).via(connectionFlow).runWith(Sink.head).map(x => (x.status, x.entity)).futureValue
  }
```

But I got errors:

```
The future returned an exception of type: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException, with message: General SSLEngine problem.
ScalaTestFailureLocation: me.archdev.restapi.HttpSpec at (HttpSpec.scala:38)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: The future returned an exception of type: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException, with message: General SSLEngine problem.
```

Any idea how to solve this ? thanks!

EDIT:
Ive tried also adding config:

```
ssl-config {
  trustManager = {
      stores = [
        { type = "PKCS12", path = "src/main/resources/mykeystore.pkcs12", password = "changeit" }
      ]
  }
}
```

with code change a bit:

```
l badSslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings(s => s.withLoose(s.loose
      .withAcceptAnyCertificate(true)
      .withDisableHostnameVerification(true)
    ))

    val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(badSslConfig)
    val connectionFlow = Http().outgoingConnectionHttps("127.0.0.1", 2001, connectionContext = badCtx)
```

but then I have an error:

> the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
> parameter must be non-empty

Tried also this code: https://gist.github.com/iRevive/4a3c7cb96374da5da80d4538f3da17cb

but then:

```
[ERROR] [09/10/2020 08:51:38.088] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://default/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-0/TLS-for-flow-3-1] the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: akka://default/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-0/TLS-for-flow-3-1: exception during creation
```

again the same..

Answer (score 0):

Ok good, this one worked finally: https://gist.github.com/iRevive/4a3c7cb96374da5da80d4538f3da17cb

before it was not working because I did not remove ssl-config.trustManager